# My next.js app is not showing proper functioning of SSR

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am making a social media app by Next.js, and storing the data in Sanity CMS. During the development, the data fetching is working fine and is updating with every page shifts and like that, but during build, the data in the page is not updating, even in SSR. Which means, if I even refresh the page, while data has updated in backend, it doesn't update in frontend. The same old data is showing up, unless I close the tab and reopen it. I have also turned off data caching, still it won't work

Please if possible tell me a solution for it, else, my app won't remain a social media app as live update is not taking place!

Comment: are you using getServersideProps right?

Comment: Yes, I am using getServerSideProps

Comment: have you tried to host your nextjs project in the vercel or netlify? or you are using npm start for checking?